# How to copy artifacts present in artifactory to specific repository?

Tags: file, powershell, download, artifactory

I am trying to copy artifacts present in artifactory to another repository , I used the powershell code like source is artifactory path and destination is repo path, But I'm facing downloadfile error with "2" arguments issue.

```
$Source = "artifactory/test/sample.zip"; 
$Dest= "repo/infra/test/admin.zip"; 
$Usr="---" 
$pwd="----" 
$webclient=New-Object System.Net.Webclient 
$webclient.credentials=New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredentials($usr,$Pwd) 
$webclient.DownloadFile($src,$dest)
```

Error after running the above code

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with 2 arguments " An exception occurred during webclient request"
```

Please specify how to resolve this issue

Comment: Please provide the code you are using and where the error is occurring

Comment: Error after running the above code like:Exception calling "DownloadFile" with 2 arguments " An exception occurred during webclient request"

Comment: $Source = "http://artifactory/test/sample.zip"
$Dest= "http://repo/infra/test/admin.zip"
$Usr="---"   
$pwd="----"                                                                                                   $webclient=New-Object System.Net.Webclient                                                          $webclient.credentials=New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredentials($usr,$Pwd)                                                                                                  $webclient.DownloadFile($src,$dest)